# Emacs - delete to first non blank character

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for key binding / function which delete from current cursor position to first non blank character

example:

```
function f() {|

    test();
```

| - cursor position

I want delete everything to "t" letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 'c-mode' there is ['M-x c-hungry-delete-forward'](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Hungry-Delete.html), which is also bound to <kbd>C-c C-d</kbd>.  So, you can create that binding in whatever programming mode you're using.

```
(define-key <whatever>-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d" 'c-hungry-delete-forward)
```

Alternatively, you can grab the package ['hungry-delete'](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hungry-delete) and use that to override the deletion commands to delete all the whitespace (as opposed to a single space).

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>M-z t t</kbd> (substitute <kbd>t</kbd> as needed :).

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good options have been presented.  In Emacs 24 (currently in pretest), you can specify <kbd>M--</kbd> to `just-one-space` or <kbd>M-SPC</kbd> to do exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I use a custom macro :

```
(fset 'jline
    [?\C-  ?\C-\M-n ?\C-a ?\C-w return])
```

(just put this small macro in your .emacs config)

Of course, you can rename the macro like you want.

---

So, the following state :

```
function f() {|



    test();
}
```

Becomes :

```
function f() {
    |test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `M-x delete-blank-lines` (which is also bound to `C-x C-o`).

From the help-docs (`C-h k C-x C-o`):

- On blank line, delete all surrounding blank lines, leaving just one.
- On isolated blank line, delete that one.
- On nonblank line, delete any immediately following blank lines.

Comment: After that, the cursor is not at the right place. Jacek wants to have the cursor just before "test()"

Comment: @SandroMunda: Jacek did not say where he wants the cursor to end up. All he says is "I want delete everything to "t" letter", which, if taken literally means he wants `function f() {test();`. I think our aesthetic sense is refusing to believe that is what he really wants though. :)

Comment: Thanks for `C-x C-o` I'm looking for this